# How do I configure Hot deployment for JSF 2.0, CDI and JPA 2.0 IN JBOSS developer studio

Tags: deployment, jsf-2, jboss7.x, cdi

Please I have searched for info on how to configure hot deployment integration between the Jboss Developer studio 5.0.0.GA AND JBOSS AS 7.1.1 for JSF 2, CDI, JPA 2 projects. All i have seen have been kind of half baked info.

Please can someone point me to a good tutorial where I can find complete info.

Comment: Hot deployment of what? If the .xhtml files is what you mean, it's enabled out of the box.

Comment: i think thats how it ought to be. strangely enough though, it does not work for me. so I am looking @maybe, i made a mistake. can u point me to some tutorial

Comment: i think thats how it ought to be. strangely enough though, it does not work for me. so I am looking @maybe, i made a mistake. can u point me to some tutorial

Comment: hot deployment of CDI beans, EJB'S AND facelets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss cannot perform hot deployments of CDI beans or EJBs out of the box. Only hot deployment of web pages (jsp, facelets) is available. If you start the server in debug mode you are able to hot swap parts of the code. I recommend trying [DCEVM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) that offers great hot redeployment of java code or [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) that's even better but it's not free.

Comment: The DECVM ALTERNATIVE corrupts my jdk installation and i mean both the java 6 and 7 alternatives.